# UserControl doesn't appear on page if dynamically added in Page.Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, asp.net-4.0

I have a custom ASP.NET user control that is added to a panel on a web page in the Page.Load method.  The control contains some Labels and a GridView.  I'm adding it to the page with this code:

```
ReportingControl rc = new ReportingControl(this.Username, this.SoaContext, transactionId, p.PaymentTypeRequestKey);
this.pnlPB.Controls.Add(rc);
```

For some reason, the controls that are added aren't actually showing up on the page. I also noticed that the controls within the control are all null but I don't know if that is part of the problem or if they are created at a later time.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a `UserControl` or a custom server control inheriting from `CompositeControl`, `WebControl`, etc.?

Generally with user controls, you load them via the ascx location, such as:

```
//load the control
Control rc= LoadControl("~/UserControls/MyControl.ascx");

//set up values as needed
rc.Username = this.Username; 

//add the control where needed
this.pnlPB.Controls.Add(rc);
```

Comment: yep - ascx files need to be compiled, not just instantiated.